# Replace apt package with compiled vers

Tags: 14.04, apt

I currently have openssl 1.0.1f installed from apt.

I need to install 1.0.2d, which I have downloaded and compiled.

What is the suggested way of installing a compiled package when one exists in the apt repo?

Also, why would the apt version appear to be so behind? I'm guessing there are circumstances I'm unaware of, but was just curious

Ubuntu 14.04

**Update**

For now I've just overwritten openssl in /usr/bin with the compiled version from /usr/local/ssl/bin

Comment: You don't - you can't remove the OpenSSL stuff @ 1.0.1f without breaking a lot of things that depend on it (pretty much anything doing SSL)

Comment: So you are implying I can expect problems now that I've overwritten it with the newer version? Which would also imply that there are breaking changes between the two openssl version?

Comment: No, but the package manager will now overwrite the executable whenever OpenSSL gets a security update in that release.  And you can't just uninstall the OpenSSL binary since a lot of stuff depends on it and it's libraries.  Because apt and dpkg are like that.

Comment: I'd first try to change to `wily` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and try to `--dry-run upgrade` the `openssl` package to see what it pulls. If it pulls a lot of stuff, then forget it and compile from source (install with `sudo checkinstall`).

Comment: @Velkan Thanks, I'm actually upgrading to 15.10 right now, and will check what version is available then.

Comment: Yes, it is 1.0.2d: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openssl

Comment: @Velkan thanks, update finished up and as you stated I'm on the version I need now. Also thankfully I'm on a later version of nginx as well.